# How to remove the last element of the array and free that part of the memory?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, memory-leaks

For example, If I have an list -

```
a = [10,2,3,5,17]
```

I want to tell python that I don't want the element 17 anymore and I want to remove that element and decrease the size of the array by 1.

I know python automatically frees all objects that are not referenced anymore, but how do I tell python that I don't want to use the last index anymore?

I basically want to make my program more memory efficient and remove all the extra space that I don't want dynamically.

Comment: `del a[-1]` get rid of the last element

Comment: what about a.pop(-1)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Thanks. This works